# Mark button as default in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

A customer asked me to style the default button in a HTML form (in quirks mode!) to look like the windows style for default buttons:

[image: Imgur]

The buttons in my HTML are 'native' buttons (i.e. they are not styled with CSS), so maybe what my customer wants is possible. But I was not able to come up with a solution to achieve this. As I realy don't know IE very good, can anyone give me a final answer wheter it is possible or not?

Btw, a CSS option would only be feasable, if the buttons still have round corners, even in IE6. And before I introduce images that look like native buttons I tell my client that this is not worth the effort.

Comment: A live example? Some pictures? Something?

Comment: Well, here you go. I normally don't like pictures when I can't upload them to the platform, because they will vanish eventually and then the context of the question will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe making use of some classic IE conditionals?

- http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/cc-plus.html
- http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

  ```
  <!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-NoMQs.css">
  <![endif]-->
  ```

Comment: I already do that so there are "round" buttons in IE6+. These buttons are not styled with CSS so that the IE renders a OS native button. (As those happen to be round in the windows default themes since XP.)